# How to exchange pointcloud between functions?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I want to write a function which takes in one pointcloud as input and provides two pointcouds as output from the arguments as shown below.

```
void func(pointcloud<T> p1,pointcloud<T> p2,pointcloud<T> p3)
{
//this is function definition
//input pointcloud = p1
//process here
//output pointcloud = p2 & p3
}

.
.
.


func(pa, pb, pc);//this is function call

void func(pointcloud<T>& p1,pointcloud<T>& p2,pointcloud<T>& p3)
{
//this definition is not working.
}
```

How to send and receive pointclouds between functions using call by reference (without copying it)? Kindly help with a **code snippet**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use shared pointers. All (or at least most) PCL classes already include a shared pointer definition (currently based on boost's shared pointer).

```
template<T>
void func(PointCloud<T>::Ptr p1, PointCloud<T>::Ptr p2, PointCloud<T>::Pr p3)
{
...
}
```

you initialize a pointer to point cloud with:

`PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>);`

*Note: Using call by reference should've also worked. What error did you get? Your snippet uses `pointcloud` instead of `PointCloud` and lacks template typename definition.*

Comment: I used ```PointCloud<PointXYZ>```. I did not get any error when I used call by reference. But, the program did not work the way it is supposed to.  **No syntactical errors were observed.**

Comment: So why did you decide that the problem is with your function definition?

Comment: Changes made to the data inside function were not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

A convention that the Boost Library people use is to return `std::pair` to spit out multiple, possibly of different type, results. i.e. something similar to :

```
using namespace pcl;

std::pair<PointCloud::Ptr, PointCloud::Ptr> foo(PointCloud::Ptr &input){
    ...
    PointCloud::Ptr output1, output2;
    output1 = boost::make_shared<PointCloud>();
    output2 = boost::make_shared<PointCloud>();
    // fill outputX here
    // ...
    return std::make_pair(output1, output2);
}
```

By using `Ptr` you avoid copying the point cloud, and just copy the wrapper `boost::shared_ptr` around the actual point data container which is much lighter. You can change the number of outputs by replacing `std::pair` with a `std::tuple` of proper size.

These are just two ways that will satisfy your needs. Any other standard library container can do the job as well if the return set is homogeneous, such as `std::vector<PointCloud::Ptr>`. Choice is yours...